# Is it possible to replicate spawn conditions for wither skeletons?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As most probably know, in terraria, it is possible to replicate certain spawn conditions artificially in controlled conditions. One example is the meteorite in which having x amount of meteorite ore, meteor heads will spawn. Similarly in minecraft, Iron Golems can be farmed for iron if one were to artifically create a village large enough for them to spawn.

That said, in minecraft, it is stated in the wiki that wither skeletons spawn in nether fortresses. Is it possible to replicate the condition for wither skeletons to spawn just like one would do in terraria or perhaps like the Village Iron Golem farm?

Answer (score 1):

No.  (Unless this has changed recently) Wither skeletons have a similar setup to slimes.  They spawn in specific marked areas, and nowhere else.

Comment: Actually they spawn in very specific areas in and around the fortress, based on the shape of the fortress.